# How do I install uuidgen

Tags: debian

I need `uuidgen` for my Linux shell scripts, but it's not on my Debian 7.1 net install.

`apt-get install uuidgen` fails, it's not clear what package I should be using, and existing questions seem to ask for alternatives rather than the *real* `uuidgen`.

Could someone with experience with `uuidgen` comment on where to get it, and why it's not in its own package?

PS.  If this is on the wrong StackExchange site, point me in the correct direction.

Comment: you might want to ask at [su] or [ask.debian.net](http://ask.debian.net)

Comment: This question was [asked and answered on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/q/621297/162825)

Comment: stackoverflow is about providing actual answers, not linking to further reading that might contain the answer.

Comment: @Giszmo the question is a duplicate.  I voted to close it sometime ago.

Comment: ok, anyway when it gets mentioned as a potential duplicate of my question, stackoverflow lists it as "unanswered". I just came here as I figured it was an easy one to answer, only to see it is actually answered, just not the way it should be. Wasting my time on stuff like this is frustrating and I provided an answer to save other people's time.

Comment: I'll accept it for completeness.

Comment: Did you try **sudo apt install uuid-runtime** ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Donal Lafferty's link states, it is contained in the package [uuid-runtime](https://packages.debian.org/stable/uuid-runtime).

Comment: The above link is now broken. See https://packages.debian.org/stable/uuid-runtime now (Debian Stretch).

Comment: The above link is now fixed :-)

Answer (score 35):

Try installing this:

```
sudo apt-get install uuid-runtime
```

Answer (score 20):

To find out which package provides a file use apt-file:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search uuidgen
```

This will yield as output

```
uuid-runtime: /usr/bin/uuidgen
```

So 'uuid-runtime' is the package to install.

```
sudo apt-get install uuid-runtime.
```